# Adjust height of the whole header bar in dashboardHeader in shiny dashboard with wraping

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I used the answer to [Adjust height of the whole header bar in dashboardHeader in shiny dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504337/adjust-height-of-the-whole-header-bar-in-dashboardheader-in-shiny-dashboard) to make my dashboardHeader smaller. When I make the browser window smaller then the header gets wrapped but the "Test"-output is not adapted.

I added a `tags$style(".content-wrapper {padding-top: 12px}")` into  `dashboardBody` which give more space, but I either would like to have no wrap of the header or the position of the output adapted.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
  # Set height of dashboardHeader
    tags$li(class = "dropdown",
            tags$style(".main-header {max-height: 20px}"),
            tags$style(".main-header .logo {height: 20px;}"),
            tags$style(".sidebar-toggle {height: 20px; padding-top: 1px !important;}"),
            tags$style(".navbar {min-height:20px !important}")
           )
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
     # Adjust the sidebar
     tags$style(".left-side, .main-sidebar {padding-top: 20px}")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(".content-wrapper {padding-top: 12px}"),   
    verbatimTextOutput('test')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
    output$test <- renderText('Test')
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could achieve what you want by replacing the `max-height` in the first `style-tag` with `min-height`, i.e.:

```
...
tags$style(".main-header {min-height: 20px}"),
...
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. I also  adjusted the sidebar replacing `tags$style(".left-side, .main-sidebar {padding-top: 20px}")` by `tags$style(".left-side, .main-sidebar {top: auto; padding-top: 0px}")`, which worked, too. Since I'am not familiar with CSS, is that ok?

Comment: I'd say yes, definitely looks better