# R Shiny Increase dashboardHeader title height

Tags: css, r, shiny

My Shiny dashboard has a `dashboardHeader` with an ajustable width `titleWidth`. However I cannot modify the height. I'd like to increase the height so that the heights of my dashboard title and image (company_logo.png) are the same. Currently, this isn't the case.

This is a an extract of my app with the code for the header.

```
#Header
header=dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard",titleWidth = 250
                   ,tags$li(class = "dropdown",
                            tags$a(href="http://www.google.com/", target="_blank", 
                                   tags$img(height = "30px", alt="SNAP Logo", src="company_logo.png")
                            )))
```

I suspect some `CSS` is involved here, but I am not very experienced at it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I already answered a question about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513507/adjust-height-of-dashboardheader-in-shinydashboard/

Comment: Thanks it was useful, but still quite tricky to change dimensions of title and image so both are perfectly aligned