# Align header elements in shiny dashboard

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard, adminlte

I'm working with `shinydashboard` to jazz up a shiny app a bit and I'm having trouble positioning some elements (eg logo) on the page. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513507/adjust-height-of-dashboardheader-in-shinydashboard#39638648) answer which was immensely useful in increasing the height of the header, but I can't quite manage the alignment issue.

[image]

There are still spaces on the left and right (red ovals) between the logo and the floating hamburger and the edges. The only way I've been able to move the hamburger has been increasing the relative size (`titleWidth = "92%"`) of the header to accommodate the longer title, but if the window is resized, the menu collapse toggle ends up in weird places. And the text in the middle I'd like to centre vertically.

One neat thing about `shinydashboard` is that if the window is made narrower, the body content rearranges so those value boxes stack. The side effect, however, if the header height is changed to accommodate the logo is:

[image: collapsed]

the header overlaps some of the content.
I'm new to css but some digging through the AdminLTE.css and the _all-skins.css that are used by `shinydashboard` got me something a bit closer:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  title = "ShinyApp",
  header = dashboardHeader(
    tags$li(
      class = "dropdown",
      tags$style(
        ".main-header {max-height: 100px; 
                      font-size:24px; 
                      font-weight:bold; 
                      line-height:24px;}"),
      tags$style(
        ".main-header .logo {height: 100px;
                             font-size:24px; 
                             font-weight:bold; 
                             line-height:24px;align:}"
      )
    ),
    title = HTML(
      "<div style = 'background-color:#3333cc; vertical-align:middle'>
       <img src = 'http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/nTX/8nj/nTX8njyEc.jpeg' align = 'left' height = '100px'>
        Long, longer, longer-still Shiny App title
       </div>"),
    titleWidth = "92%"
  ),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    width = "300px",
    sidebarMenu(
      tags$style(
        ".main-sidebar {float:top; margin-top:40px; padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px}"
      ),
      h2("Sidebar heading"),
      sliderInput(inputId = "slider1",
                  label = "Some slider",
                  min = 5, 
                  max = 500,
                  value = 100, 
                  step = 5),
      numericInput(inputId = "num1",
                   label = HTML("Value in <em>units</em>"),
                   min = 1000, 
                   step = 250, 
                   value = 500)
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML(
          ".skin-blue .main-header .navbar {background-color: #3333cc}
           .skin-blue .main-header .navbar .sidebar-toggle:hover {background-color: red}
           .skin-blue .main-header .logo {background-color: #3333cc;border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;}
           .skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {background-color: #3333cc;}
           .content-wrapper {float:top; margin-top:40px}"
        )
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      valueBox(width = 6,
               value = "20%",
               icon = icon("thumbs-up"),
               subtitle = "some value",
               color = "orange"),
      valueBox(width = 6,
               value = "30,000 units",
               icon = icon("truck"),
               subtitle = "some other value",
               color = "orange")
    )
  )
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

yielding

[image: attempted solution]

from another answer, I got something like padding to shift the sidebar down and took a guess at making a similar modification to the .content-wrapper

```
.main-sidebar {float:top; margin-top:40px; padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px}
```

and

```
.content-wrapper {float:top; margin-top:40px}
```

collapsed mode is okay, but there are now two vertical scroll bars and widening the window again, there's now a black separator between the top of the body and the header. The 40px I used for the margin-top was purely trial and error.

To summarise:

- I'd like to align header logo left (maybe also sidebar toggle right,
  but can live with where it is)
- Vertically-align the header text
- Accommodate a longer title (eg titleWidth = 95%)
- Not overlap body content with header when viewed in
  a narrower window.

Aside from the above, regarding the header text, I have tried setting `style = "vertical-align:middle"` in various places around the text and logo image definitions as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489340/vertically-align-text-next-to-an-image?rq=1) (one example is still in the sample code), but the text remains stubbornly at the top. Presumably there is a css element I haven't found that controls it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Note sample code modified to use random stock internet photo rather than android logo to facilitate reproducibility of example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please note that I am not a `CSS` expert so not every solution might be ideal.

> Remove unnecessary vertical scroll bars

```
.wrapper {overflow-y: hidden;}
```

> I'd like to align header logo left (maybe also sidebar toggle right, but can live with where it is)

Override `padding` to `0px`:

```
.main-header .logo {
  padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

Float `sidebar-toggle` to the right:

```
.sidebar-toggle {
  float: right !important;
}
```

> Vertically-align the header text

`vertical-align` has no effect, but you can use `line-height` to set the title where you want.

```
.main-header .logo {
  line-height: 85px !important;
  padding: 0 0px;
}
```

> Accommodate a longer title (eg titleWidth = 95%)

Increase the `max-height` of the `main-header`. Alternatively you could decrease the amount of text so that it fits small-middle screens better.

```
.main-header {
  max-height: 200px !important;
}
```

> Not overlap body content with header when viewed in a narrower window.

Remove `margin-top` from `.content-wrapper {float:top; margin-top:40px}"`. This alongside with the previous change should be sufficient.

Complete CSS including yours:

```
.skin-blue .main-header .navbar {background-color: #3333cc}
.skin-blue .main-header .navbar .sidebar-toggle:hover {background-color: red}
.skin-blue .main-header .logo {background-color: #3333cc;border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;}
.skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {background-color: #3333cc;}
.content-wrapper {float:top;}
.wrapper {overflow-y: hidden;}
.main-header {
  max-height: 200px !important;
}
.sidebar-toggle {
  float: right !important;
}

.main-header .logo {
  line-height: 85px !important;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that and the helpful explanations - more expert with css than I. Your point is taken about trying for shorter titles, but in the case of longer ones, do you have any idea what controls the wrapping? Previously, the title wrapped when narrowing the window but with this solution, the longer title is truncated. Not critical, but curious.

Comment: Probably [media-queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp), but I haven't digged into `AdminLTE` enough. I'm gonna come back to it if I have the time.